# print a line from every 5 elements of a column

Tags: awk, printf

I am looking for a way to select a column (e. g. eighth column) of a data file  and write the first five numbers of that column in a row, the next five numbers in second row, and so on.

I have been testing with `awk` and `printf` without success.

Answer (score 3):

The `awk` way to do this is to switch from using `OFS` and `ORS` to separate the output using the modulus function:

```
$ seq 1 20 | awk '{printf "%s", $1 (NR % 5 ? OFS : ORS)}'
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20
```

Change `$1` to `$8` for the eigth column for example and `NR % 5` to `NR % 10` for rows of 10 instead of 5. The `seq` command just generate a single column of digits from 1 to 20 used for demonstration.

---

I also find using `xargs` useful for this kind of thing:

```
$ seq 1 20 | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -n5
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20
```

The `awk` isn't necessary for the example as `seq` only produces a single column however for your question change `$1` to `$8` to select only the eighth column from your input. With this approach you could also switch out `awk` with `cut`.

Comment: +1. I'd have written it as `awk '{printf "%s%s", $1, (NR % 5 ? OFS : ORS)}'` but I can't think of any case where your approach of string concatenation wouldn't work just as well, unless of course you wanted to print numbers instead of strings and rely on numeric conversion for the output format (e.g. `%.2f` instead of `%s`), but that's not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

This will also produce the format requested

```
seq 1 20 | awk '{printf("%s ", $1); if (NR % 5 == 0) printf("\n")}'
```

where $1 indicates de column number which could be changed when passing an archive to the awk line.